# Creating Standard user to Admin user verses new Admin user

Tags: macbook-pro, user-account

[image: empty desktop folder in home folder]To create a new user is there a difference between creating it first as a standard user then making it a admin user account compared to just creating a new user account as admin? The reason Im asking is because I am wondering if the current admin user account has any influence on what you end up when a new user is created. I want to avoid that. I found my MacBook Pro book and Im going to follow it to learn how to use my MacBook Pro and its saying the folder and files you see on the Desktop are determined by the contents the Desktop folder, which is located within your Home folder. The Desktop folder in my Home folder is empty. So I want to start over and have everything how where it should be.